# How to assign several names to lat-lon observations

Tags: r, distance, geographic-distance

I have two dataframes: `df1` contains observations with lat-lon coordinates; `df2` has names with lat-lon coordinates. I want to create a new variable `df1$names` which has for each observation the names of `df2` that are within a specified distance to that observation.

Some sample data for `df1`:

```
df1 <- structure(list(lat = c(52.768, 53.155, 53.238, 53.253, 53.312, 53.21, 53.21, 53.109, 53.376, 53.317, 52.972, 53.337, 53.208, 53.278, 53.316, 53.288, 53.341, 52.945, 53.317, 53.249), lon = c(6.873, 6.82, 6.81, 6.82, 6.84, 6.748, 6.743, 6.855, 6.742, 6.808, 6.588, 6.743, 6.752, 6.845, 6.638, 6.872, 6.713, 6.57, 6.735, 6.917), cat = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), diff = c(6.97305555555555, 3.39815972222222, 14.2874305555556, -0.759791666666667, 34.448275462963, 4.38783564814815, 0.142430555555556, 0.698599537037037, 1.22914351851852, 7.0008912037037, 1.3349537037037, 8.67978009259259, 1.6090162037037,    25.9466782407407, 9.45068287037037, 4.76284722222222, 1.79163194444444, 16.8280787037037, 1.01336805555556, 3.51240740740741)), .Names = c("lat", "lon", "cat", "diff"), row.names = c(125L, 705L, 435L, 682L, 186L, 783L, 250L, 517L, 547L, 369L, 618L, 280L, 839L, 614L, 371L, 786L, 542L, 100L, 667L, 785L), class = "data.frame")
```

Some sample data for `df2`:

```
df2 <- structure(list(latlonloc = structure(c(6L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("Boelenslaan", "Borgercompagnie", "Froombosch", "Garrelsweer", "Stitswerd", "Tinallinge"), class = "factor"), lat = c(53.356789, 53.193886, 53.311237, 53.111339, 53.360848, 53.162031), lon = c(6.53493, 6.780792, 6.768608, 6.82354, 6.599604, 6.143804)), .Names = c("latlonloc", "lat", "lon"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Creating a distance matrix with the `geosphere` package:

```
library(geosphere)
mat <- distm(df1[,c('lon','lat')], df2[,c('lon','lat')], fun=distHaversine)
```

The resulting distances are in meters (at least I think they are, else something is wrong with the distance matrix).

The specified distance is calculated with `(df1$cat)^2)*1000`. I tried `df1$names <- df2$latlonloc[apply(distmat, 1, which(distmat < ((df1$cat)^2)*1000 ))]`, but get an error message:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'which(distmat < ((df1$cat)^2) * 1000)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

This is probably not the correct appraoch, but what I need is this:

`df1$names <- #code or function which gives me a string of names which are within a specified distance of the observation`

How can I create a string with the names that are within a specified distance of the observations?

Comment: When you call `apply`, the third argument needs to be a function, either simply the function name or a complete function with an argument that will correspond to each element of the first argument to `apply`. You need something like `apply(distmat, 1, function(x) ...)` where `...` is some function body that uses the `x` argument. I can't tell from your code what you want/need that to be, though.

Comment: @Thomas I edited the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: What do you expect `which(distmat < ((df1$cat)^2) * 1000)` to give you?

Comment: @Thomas I expect that it gives me a set of names which are within a certain distance (`(df1$cat)^2)*1000`) of the observation.

Comment: `which` is documented to give integers. Why would you think it gives names?

Comment: @IShouldBuyABoat based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968692/how-to-assign-a-name-to-lat-long-observations-based-on-shortest-distance) I guessed that I might achieve the desired result with `which` as well.

Comment: `which.min` was being used to select an item from a character vector by _numeric_ indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to operate on each row of `df1` (or `mat`) in order to figure out, for each row how far away each object in `df2` is. From that, you can pick the ones that meet your distance criterion.

I think you're getting a little confused about the use of `apply` and about the use of `which`. To really have `which` work for you, you need to apply it to each row of `mat` whereas your current code applies it to the entire `mat` matrix. Also note that it is hard to use `apply` here because you're comparing each row of `mat` against a corresponding element of a vector defined by `((df1$cat)^2)*1000)`. So, I will instead show you examples using `sapply` and `lapply`. You could also use `mapply` here, but I think the `sapply`/`mapply` syntax is clearer.

To address your desired output, I show two examples. One returns a list containing, for each row in `df1`, the names of items in `df2` that are within the distance threshold. This won't easily go back into your original `df1` as a variable because each element in the list can contain multiple names. The second example pastes those names together as a single comma-separated character string in order to create the new variable you're looking for.

Example 1:

```
out1 <- lapply(1:nrow(df1), function(x) {
    df2[which(mat[x,] < (((df1$cat)^2)*1000)[x]),'latlonloc']
})
```

Result:

```
> str(out1)
List of 20
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 2
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 4
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 6 4 5
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..: 4
 $ : Factor w/ 6 levels "Boelenslaan",..:
```

Example 2:

```
out2 <- sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(x) {
    paste(df2[which(mat[x,] < (((df1$cat)^2)*1000)[x]),'latlonloc'], collapse=',')
})
```

Result:

```
> out2
 [1] ""                                 ""                                
 [3] ""                                 ""                                
 [5] ""                                 ""                                
 [7] ""                                 "Borgercompagnie"                 
 [9] ""                                 "Garrelsweer"                     
[11] ""                                 ""                                
[13] ""                                 ""                                
[15] "Tinallinge,Garrelsweer,Stitswerd" ""                                
[17] ""                                 ""                                
[19] "Garrelsweer"                      ""
```

I think the second of these is probably closest to what you're going for.

Comment: Example 2 gives me the desired answer. Thanx!