Fast method of correcting for spatial autocorrelation in global dataset
This is a general question. I have a global dataset of ~60,000 protected areas (PA) distributed globally. I am modeling change in species richness change_alpha for each protected area between two time periods.
Currently using R package brms to model the effects of PA size (interacting with continent), latitude, and longitude on change in species richness. Latitude and longitude are included as fixed effects assuming that the magnitude of species' range shifts are related to geography.
model1 <- brm(change_alpha ~ PA_size * continent + latitude + longitude)

I'd like to account for spatial autocorrelation as PAs are not randomly distributed. Currently, I'm considering R package spaMM and accounting for spatial autocorrelation via a Matern random effect.
model2 <- fitme(change_alpha ~ PA_size * continent + latitude + longitude + Matern(1 | longitude + latitude), data = dat, family = "gaussian")

However, with 60,000 items and a global distribution I'm worried the model would take an exorbitant amount of time to run. I'm wondering what would be considered the fastest method for handling spatial autocorrelation in this case? It seems that adding a Markov random field (MRF) approximation to constrain the Matern could speed things, but there are additional parameters (mesh resolution) for which I have little idea on how to parameterize a priori.

This seems like a pretty big general task. The simplest/easiest way I can think of doing it would be to add a MRF based only on nearest neighbors (I think you can do this in brms with s(..., bs = "mrf"). You'd still need to find a sufficiently efficient way to construct the neighbor list (maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49272572/190277 ) ?

@BenBolker, thanks! I'll look into this approach. I was also thinking of using SPDE with a mesh, possibly in INLA or spaMM.
