# Find 5 closest stations from lat/lon coordinates

Tags: r, r-sp

I'm trying to find the 5 closest stations from one data set (`set1`) to another data set (`set2`).  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442506/find-nearest-points-of-latitude-and-longitude-from-different-data-sets-with-diff) post is what I'm using as a basis and it seems simple to find the single closest, but I'm writing `for` loops to deal with it and is not efficient.  Furthermore, I'm getting and error and don't understand why it's not working.  Ideally, I would like to use `set1` to find the closest stations in `set2`, find the 5 closest stations, and add a column for each station, for each unique id from `set1`.

Edit: This question is different from [How to assign a name to lat-long observations based on shortest distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968692/how-to-assign-a-name-to-lat-long-observations-based-on-shortest-distance) because I'm trying to find the 5 closest stations, not just a single distance.  Also, the method is different for finding the minimum.  Please reopen this question.

dput:

```
set1 <- structure(list(id = c(5984, 7495, 4752, 2654, 4578, 9865, 3265, 
1252, 4679, 1346), lat = c(48.39167, 48.148056, 48.721111, 47.189167, 
47.054443, 47.129166, 47.306667, 47.84, 47.304167, 48.109444), 
    lon = c(13.671114, 12.866947, 15.94223, 11.099736, 12.958342, 
    14.203892, 11.86389, 16.526674, 16.193064, 17.071392)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", "lat", "lon"))

set2 <- structure(list(id = 1:10, lat = structure(c(35.8499984741211, 
34.75, 70.9329986572266, 78.25, 69.6829986572266, 74.515998840332, 
70.3659973144531, 67.265998840332, 63.6990013122559, 60.1990013122559
), .Dim = 10L), lon = structure(c(14.4829998016357, 32.4000015258789, 
-8.66600036621094, 15.4670000076294, 18.9160003662109, 19.0160007476807, 
31.0990009307861, 14.3660001754761, 9.59899997711182, 11.0830001831055
), .Dim = 10L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", 
"lat", "lon"))
```

Code:

```
library(rgeos)
library(sp)


set1sp <- SpatialPoints(set1)
set2sp <- SpatialPoints(set2)
for (i in length(set1$id)){
  for (j in 4:9){
    if(i == 1) {
      sub <- set2
      set1[i,j] <- apply(gDistance(set1sp, set2sp, byid=TRUE), 1, which.min)
      sub <- filter(sub, id != set1[i,j])}
    else{
      set1[i,j] <- apply(gDistance(set1sp, set2sp, byid=TRUE), 1, which.min)
      sub <- filter(sub, id != set1[i,j])}
  }
}
```

Output error:

```
 Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, j, value = c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L,  : 
  replacement has 10 rows, data has 1
```

Comment: It's likely that the error is being generated because you are missing a `1:` before `length(set1$id)`

Comment: What are `set1sp` and `set2sp`? They are not defined. Also, what projection system are your points in? And if you only want to add 5 columns, you probably want `j in 4:8` rather than 9.

Comment: @JaredSmith Sorry I added set1sp and set2sp

Comment: Check your apply lines. [Apply()](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/apply) returns a vector or array but you set it to a data frame cell value (row,col).

Comment: @JaredSmith Thanks, but  changed the for loop to include `1:` and it still is not working

Comment: @Parfait This apply function works with the same example I posted in the question, so it should work fine.  However, I did change it and ams till getting the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set the projection system and the coordinates for `set1sp` and `set2sp` in order to make `gDistance` work. I assumed WGS84.

```
dummyset1= set1
dummyset2= set2
coordinates(set1) = c('lon', 'lat')
coordinates(set2) = c('lon', 'lat')
proj4string(set1) = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
proj4string(set2) = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
set1sp = set1
set2sp = set2
set1 = dummyset1
set2 = dummyset2
```

This loop will return the output you wanted based on using the general structure of your for loop.

```
for (i in 1:length(set1$id)){
    #Store the projected data in a dummy variable sub
    sub <- set2sp
    for (j in 4:8){
        if (j == 4){
           set1[i,j] <- apply(gDistance(set2sp['id'], set1sp['id'][i,], byid=TRUE), 1, which.min)
           #Remove the index of the closest point from sub.
           sub <- sub[which(sub$id != set1[i,j]), ]
        }
        else {
           #Note that sub is now being checked instead of set2sp. This is because sub has had the index of the closest point removed.
           set1[i,j] <- apply(gDistance(sub['id'], set1sp['id'][i,], byid=TRUE), 1, which.min)
           sub <- sub[which(sub$id != set1[i,j]), ]
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting output is:

```
set1
   id      lat      lon V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
1  5984 48.39167 13.67111 10  1  8  7  6
2  7495 48.14806 12.86695 10  1  8  7  6
3  4752 48.72111 15.94223 10  1  8  7  6
4  2654 47.18917 11.09974  1  9  8  7  6
5  4578 47.05444 12.95834  1  9  8  7  6
6  9865 47.12917 14.20389  1  9  8  7  6
7  3265 47.30667 11.86389  1  9  8  7  6
8  1252 47.84000 16.52667  1  9  8  7  6
9  4679 47.30417 16.19306  1  9  8  7  6
10 1346 48.10944 17.07139  1  9  8  7  6
```

Comment: This certainly worked, but I'm getting this error: `50: In RGEOSDistanceFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, "rgeos_distance") :
  Spatial object 2 is not projected; GEOS expects planar coordinates`

Comment: I think that warning is a result of using degree coordinates instead of planar coordinates (e.g. UTM coordinates). You can use `spTransform()` to convert your data into a planar system appropriate for your region.

Comment: Try `order(apply(spDists(set1,set2),2,min))[1:5]` : `spDists` computes the great circle distances matrix from long/lat data, as defined above; `apply` takes the minimum for every column (point in set2, over set1), order and `[1:5]` finds the five closest. This is not a duplicate question as mentioned above.

Comment: @EdzerPebesma Thanks, but I tried your code and it didn't work.  I get this error: `replacement has 5 rows, data has 1 `  Mind creating another answer using this?

Answer (score 1):

The following computes great circle distances from all points in set 2 wrt set 1. It then takes the minimum over set 1, and orders them; then plots.

```
library(sp)
coordinates(set1) = c('lon', 'lat')
coordinates(set2) = c('lon', 'lat')
proj4string(set1) = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
proj4string(set2) = "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
d = apply(spDists(set1,set2),2,min)
order(d)[1:5]
# [1]  1 10  9  2  8
plot(set2, pch=2, axes=TRUE)
points(set1)
o = order(d)[1:5]
points(set2[o,], col = 'red', pch=16)
```

[image]